# how to redirect routes in Netlify using vite and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, netlify, vite

I need to redirect to the home of a react project on Netlify but I'm using vite.

I used to do it using CRA (create-react-app) and creating the **_redirects** file in the public folder with this configuration.

```
/*  /index.html 200
```

How would I do it in vitejs?

Answer (score 7):

Try creating a `netlify.toml` file in root directory.

in **netlify.toml**

```toml
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
```

Comment: if this doesn't work... check [THIS](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/2571) out.

Answer (score 2):

[@sarthak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5406448/sarthak)'s answer is good, you just get to copy `_redirects` to the `dist` folder upon build. Although there is an easier way to do so.

Just create a folder named `public` and put your `_redirects` there. Everything in this folder will be copied to `dist` as is.

Reference: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, we need to locate _redirects file inside the public folder, which will be moved into dist folder (netlify considers it as the root when we use vite) automatically during build time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### Using netlify.toml file

1. Create netlify.toml file in the root of the repository
2. Insert the below snippet in the file.

---

```
[[redirects]]
from="/*"
to="{base URL of your site}"
status=200
```

---

this worked for me.

### Reference

Netlify redirect configuration [Redirect options](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/redirect-options/)

Netlify configuration file (netlify.toml) [Configuration file](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/#syntax-for-the-netlify-configuration-file)

Answer (score -2):

You could create the same _redirects file in the root and then modify build script to add it to dist folder like below

```
  "build": "vite build && cp ./_redirects ./dist/_redirects",
```

Comment: You could simply create the `_redirects` file inside the `public` folder

Comment: Back when this was answered the react vite plugin did not create public folder on setup, hence this was a workaround. Although you could create a public folder as Victor mentioned in his answer.